# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when mocking static method using EasyMock+PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, static-methods, powermock, easymock

I am trying to mock static method using EasyMock+PowerMock. If I dont mock the static method, then I get the exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError but with a different stack trace which is purely due to my code files and the error is obvious. However, if I mock the static method using EasyMock+PowerMock, the line PowerMock.mockStaticNice(Classname.class) throws the same exception but with a different stack trace. The stack trace is:

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:386)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:175)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:114)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:88)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:79)
        at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doCreateMock(PowerMock.java:2212)
        at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doMock(PowerMock.java:2163)
        at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStaticNice(PowerMock.java:331)
        at PackageName(ClassName.java:125)
............................
```

The line 125 is PowerMock.mockStaticNice(Classname.class)

I have already tried this:
1) Mention class name containing static method in PrepareForTest({class1.class, class2.class, class3.class})
2) Mock static methods in @Before annotation. 

I am stuck with this problem for the last 2 days. Kindly suggest solutions.

Comment: Just for the record: you understand that *static* is an abnormality that simply should be avoided in good OO designs? And surprise: no static calls, no need for PowerMock.

Comment: I understand that. But I am just editing someone's previous code, so I don't have any option apart from mocking the static method.

Comment: Well, you could **add** an interface/wrapper class and change the static call to use that wrapper; but of course; that carries some risk; and in that case, it is probably not worth the effort. In that sense: I rarely see answers here that really say "this is how you get it to work with powermock"; so maybe you are better off posting to the Powermock google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/powermock

Comment: Thanks! I will post the doubt in that google group. Adding wrapper class is not possible because I am not allowed to change previously written code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I understood from your explanation the `ExceptionInInitializerError` is thrown during static initialisation of class?  I've made such conclusion, because according to stacktrace the line `PowerMock.mockStaticNice(Classname.class)` is a first place where the class `Classname` is being loaded.

In this case you have to use `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor(`PackageName.ClassName`). More information you may find in PowerMock documentation: [Suppress Unwanted Behavior](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this too but just wrote class name in the suppress line, didn't include package name. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error on VSCode, this is because your VSCode is on a newer Java version.

You can open the Command Palette with `CMD` + `Shift` + `P` and search `Java: Configure Java Runtime`.

From there you can pick an older Java version, for example Java 8 instead of Java 17. My Java 8 was located at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home`.