# Mockito spy() causes java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to use initialize a regular Mockito spy like this

```java
StorageItem storageItemMock = Mockito.spy(cargoAdministration
                                     .addCargo(CargoType.MIXED, 
                                               new CustomerImp("Human"),
                                               BigDecimal.ONE, 
                                               hazards, true, false));

cargoAdministration.inspect(storageItemMock.getPosition());

verify(storageItemMock, times(1)).getCargo().inspect();
```

The `addCargo` method returns a `StorageItem` so that should not be the problem. I want to `verify` a method from the `StorageItem` spy.

Every time I try to run this test I get following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in java.lang.CompoundEnumeration@3d34d211

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during attachment using: ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.Compound{attachmentProviders=[ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForJigsawVm.INSTANCE, ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForJ9Vm.INSTANCE, ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForToolsJarVm.JVM_ROOT, ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForToolsJarVm.JDK_ROOT, ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForToolsJarVm.MACINTOSH]}

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can not attach to current VM
```

Comment: What method call do you want to verify? I don't see a good reason why you wouldn't just be able to verify the values in the returned `StorageItem` itself, since that is the result of the method - but then again, there's not enough context to judge.

Comment: My `StorageItem` has an `inspect` method which updates the `lastInspectionDate`. I want to `verify` that that my `cargoAdministrion` invokes the `inspect` method from the `StorageItem`

Comment: I updated my question with the `verify`code. Sorry not really used to post questions here.

Comment: So this does not really have anything to do with your error message, but why do you not have separate test cases for `addCargo` and `inspect`? Then you can verify the result of `addCargo` by checking the return value, and verify calls using a mock for the ´inspect`.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow you but I do test my `addCargo` method separately. But to test my `inspect` method I need to add a cargo to the `cargoAdministration`. So by testing the `inspect` method from the `cargoAdminitration` I want to verify that it invokes the `inspect` method of the right `cargo` object.

Comment: So you're saying, if the cargo you want to `inspect` isn't present in the administration, it will fail? How does the administration verify it has been added before? Because I would rather create a mock and manipulate it so admin will accept it as present, rather than spy.

Comment: So if the the `inspect` method needs a storagePosition which is the key of my `storageItem`/ `cargo` Map. If there is no object found by this key my class will throw a `cargoNotFoundExcepetion`. I think the problem is, that if I insert a mock the `cargoAdmin` will store the `item` in an unknown position because I don't know which key it gave to this `item`. So I thought I use a spy that I can just use its position for testing the `inspect` method.

Comment: Sorry some typos at the first sentence. Meant: So the `inspect` method needs a `storagePosition` which is the key of my `storageItem`/ `cargo` Map.

Comment: If you're seeing this issue on VSCode, check out my answer on [StackOverflow - 77581473#7460739](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77581473/7460739).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArgumentCaptor instead of Spy in your case in order to catch the element passed to your method;

```java
@Mock
StorageItem storageItemMock;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<Hazard> hazardCaptor;

@Test
public void yourTest(){
  // assertion
  verify(storageItemMock, times(2)). addCargo(hazardCaptor.capture());

  // mail is sent after notification
  Hazard mailEvent = (Haeard) hazardCaptor.getAllValues().get(1);
  assertThat(hazard.getter(), equalTo(the passed object));
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to verify a method from the StorageItem spy. Its not a bout the hazards sorry for the miss understanding theree

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what causes the error, but

```
verify(storageItemMock, times(1)).getCargo().inspect();
```

will not work, even if `storageItemMock` is a spy - the `verify` can check that `getCargo()` is called on the spy, but not the `inspect()` call because that's called on a real object (and out of range of the `verify()`).

As for the cargo/position/map issue, I feel the `addPosition`-method does too much; calculate the key, creates the actual item, puts it in a map. If you at least delegate the item creation, you can use proper mocks to test this.

```
class Administration {
    ItemCreator creator;
    StorageItem add(...) {
       StorageItem item = creator.create(...);
       map.store(item.getPosition(), item);
       return item;
    }
    void inspect(Position position) {
       StorageItem item = map.get(position);
       item.getCargo().inspect();
    }
}

// test
void testAdd() {
    when(creator.create(any(), ...)).thenReturn(item);
    when(item.getPosition()).thenReturn(position);
    admin.add(...);
    verify(creator).create(...);
    verify(map).store(position, item);
}
void testInspect() {
    item = mock(StorageItem.class);
    cargo = mock(Cargo.class);
    when(item.getPosition()).thenReturn(position);
    when(item.getCargo()).thenReturn(cargo);
    when(map.get(position)).thenReturn(item);

    admin.inspect(item);

    verify(map).get(position); // check map was queried
    verify(item).getPosition();  // check item's position was used
    verify(item).getCargo();  // check cargo was retrieved
    verify(cargo).inspect();   // check inspect was performed (the only really important check)
}
```

Comment: The exception is cause in the line where I initialize the spy so I think that's still a problem, but however I realize that I might should refactor my BL before keep on going.

Comment: Ah and the reason why I need to call `getCargo` on `storageItem` first is because my `storageItem` contains the `cargo`. But you right that it is out of range for the spy.